# A ggplot plot is appearing different when run in script and rmarkdown file

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr, r-markdown

This is my code

```
Outlier_DF%>%
ggplot(. )+
        geom_bar(aes(x=(outlier_count), fill=as.character(outlier_count)))+
        facet_grid(Year~CVI_Quintile2)+
          ggtitle("Number of Outliers observed per Census Tract")+
          xlab("Risk Level")+ylab("Geography_Year observations")+
            scale_fill_discrete(name="Number of Outliers\n Per Census Tract")
```

This is the incorrectly produced graph from the Rmarkdown.
[image: This is the incorrectly produced graph from the Rmarkdown.]

This is the correctly produced graph from the Rscript.
[image: This is the correctly produced graph from the Rscript.]

Here is a glimpse(Outlier_DF):

```
Observations: 474
Variables: 16
$ CVI_Quintile2         <fctr> Moderate Risk, High Risk, Very High Risk, Ve...
$ CVI                   <dbl> 32.0, 40.8, 48.0, 58.4, 67.3, 60.8, 31.0, 32....
$ Geography_Year        <fctr> Census Tract 6001_2012, Census Tract 6001_20...
$ Geography             <fctr> Census Tract 6001, Census Tract 6001, Census...
$ Year                  <int> 2012, 2013, 2014, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2012, 201...
$ PercEducHSorHigher    <dbl> 92.0, 90.6, 87.6, 68.4, 69.7, 76.7, 91.2, 90....
$ PercUnemployment      <dbl> 8.2, 8.2, 7.5, 10.1, 11.4, 5.6, 4.4, 5.8, 5.2...
$ PercSSinc             <dbl> 1.9, 3.0, 5.0, 8.8, 8.5, 8.6, 6.4, 7.4, 9.4, ...
$ PercNoHealthCov       <dbl> 10.9, 12.3, 12.8, 17.4, 20.0, 19.5, 8.7, 7.6,...
$ PercDisability        <dbl> 9.0, 9.2, 11.1, 9.5, 8.7, 6.9, 6.9, 6.7, 6.7,...
$ PercRentHigher        <dbl> 45.8, 58.4, 51.3, 59.2, 64.9, 60.9, 46.2, 35....
$ PercBelowPoverty      <dbl> 3.2, 4.7, 4.8, 17.3, 20.9, 17.5, 5.5, 2.6, 7....
$ outlier_count         <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
$ Clustered_Educ        <chr> NA, NA, NA, "Clustered", "Clustered", NA, NA,...
$ Clustered_Poverty     <chr> NA, NA, NA, "Clustered", "Clustered", "Cluste...
$ Clustered_NoHealthCov <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, N...
```

As far as I can understand there is no reason which I know of that would cause the different/incorrect plot in the Rmarkdown compared to the Rscript running the same block of code. I have checked the data and code multiple times to see if it might be a sequencing issue when running the Rmarkdown, but that doesn't seem to be the issue because if the markdown is run piece by piece the resulting graph is the correct one. I would be happy to hear of other people experiencing the issue or a suggestion about what might be causing the error because I cannot figure it out for the life of me.

Comment: What's wrong? Just the size? That can be set in the chunk options with `fig.height` and `fig.width`

Comment: @RichardTelford I'ts kind of hard to tell, but panels (2, 2) and (3, 4) do seem changed. Also the y-axis is different.

Comment: Clear your workspace and cache directory, if you are using one.  It is possible that local changes in your interactive session have been made resulting in the difference between the two graphics.